# Firebase hosting, and external APIs

Tags: heroku, dns, firebase, firebase-hosting

#### Background

I'm currently using Heroku, running a single *Hobby Dyno* to serve both static assets and a simple API using node.js. I'm now looking to separate the static delivery and API into different dependencies. Having looked around, I'm now considering Firebase for static hosting.

#### Question

Using Firebase static hosting, is it possible to configure the DNS, or setup a URL rewrite, to make external API calls for a given URL, e.g.

```
http://myapp.com/api -> external API call to http://myapp.herokuapp.com/
http://myapp.com/*   -> serve static file
```

If not, is it possible to configure a DNS entry to point `www` to Firebase, and `api` to Heroku?

#### Bonus Question

If possible; would this API call count as a cross-origin request? Preferably all requests would be made against the Firebase domain, and then everything done behind closed doors.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to have Firebase Hosting [rewrite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-rewrites) the URL to a different server. While it is possible to have Firebase Hosting [redirect](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-rewrites) the request to the Heroku server, that likely won't help you.

The common approach is indeed to split this in the DNS. Have `api.myapp.com` point to Heroku and `www.myapp.com` to Firebase Hosting.

Comment: After a bit of research, I think this might be my best option; have a CNAME for `@` and `www` point to Firebase, and a separate CNAME for `api` to point to Heroku. I'll have a play around, thanks Frank!

Comment: This way each Ajax request to the API will take more time to execute (because of CORS preflight)